# Parse.com webapp "parse deploy" issue

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse4j

I am using parse javascript cloud code on windows.

I am following steps given here https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows

So far I am able to create directory structure using `parse new`. Which looks like:

```
CloudCodeDemo
    -config/
      global.json
    -cloud/
      main.js
    -public/
      index.html
```

Then I ran `parse deploy` in CloudCodeDemo directory but is shows **parse is not recognized as an internal or external command**

**EDIT**:

[image]

```
I followed instructions:
Copy both exe files to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
Open PowerShell (x86)in administrator mode
Type .\ParseConsole.exe
```

But now I am facing this issue when I type `.\ParseConsole.exe` in power shell. below is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: make sure your current directory is project cd /Project_Dir

Comment: @MeghsDhameliya Yes I am in my project directory i.e. CloudCodeDemo and firing parse deploy from there only sir

Comment: @MeghsDhameliya please see the screenshot I have attached.

Comment: Are you running this command in `cmd` or `powershell` ?

Comment: Looks like you created the new app from Parse console (in powershell) but tried to deploy from cmd.

Comment: Will not work in cmd, use the parse command line tool, which opens in powershell

Comment: @AkshayArora I created app using cmd and deploying also in cmd

Comment: @AkshayArora from where I can get parse command line tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I came to know that you don't have the Parse command line tool. It is clearly mentioned on the Parse Docs that you must download and install the tool.

Have a look at this article. It also contains the link from where to download. 
[Parse Blog](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-command-line-tools-available-for-windows/)

Comment: yeah I got the tool from the link you gave. But why it is not able to update to latest version ?

Comment: If you are on windows, and you tried to update it through the command line, it won't work. It updates from command line only on Mac.

Comment: In this link: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows on point 1, in first line they say "The command line tool is available here". You need to click on "here" to get the latest one :p

Comment: Yeah from there I can get parse-windows-2.1.3.exe file

Comment: Then what I supposed to do with that .exe file

Comment: This is actually the latest version, if you install it, it will open in powershell like the previous version you actually have. btw, I am using older version without any problems till now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83833/discussion-between-mahendra-kawde-and-akshay-arora).

Comment: I followed your instructions 
Copy both exe files to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
Open PowerShell (x86)
Type .\ParseConsole.exe
open powershell in administrator mode

Comment: But now I am getting something else as an error. I have updated post with screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

you have to install on parse.exe file in the following directory C:\Windows\ System32 so you can recognize commands parse

Comment: Thank you so much for this !

Answer (score 3):

I just copied/installed(CTRL+C->CTRL+V) parse.exe from the [download page](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/releases/) into C:\Windows\System32 and then I could use the parse commands trough my Git CMD.

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, none of the comment above has given the reason for the error you keep getting, however the solution without switching to Powershell is to edit your "environment variables" from "Advance System Settings" by adding "PATH" as the variable name and using the directory where your parse.exe is located as the variable value.